# IndexingError: Too many indexers , appears while creating plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've found a problem while learning about creating the financial plots.
This code is a part of tutorial, but in my case it doesn't work.
I tried each option about indexing like: .iloc , .values , (axis = 0) and everyting what had been written on the net. Could you help me ?
Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set(style = 'darkgrid', context = 'talk', palette = 'Dark2')


data = pd.read_pickle('data.pickle')
data = data['Close']
data = data['MSFT']

my_year_month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%y')  
short_SMA = data.rolling(window = 20, min_periods = 0).mean()
long_SMA = data.rolling(window = 100, min_periods = 0).mean()

short_EMA = data.ewm(span = 20, adjust = False, min_periods = 0).mean()
long_EMA = data.ewm(span = 100, adjust = False, min_periods = 0).mean()


start = pd.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = pd.datetime(2020,4,21)

data_EMA_difference = data - short_EMA

trading_positions = data_EMA_difference.apply(np.sign) * 1/3


trading_positions_final = trading_positions.shift(1)

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize = (16,9))

ax1.plot(data.loc[start:end, :].index, data.loc[start:end,"MSFT"], label = "Price")
ax1.plot(short_EMA.loc[start:end, :].index, short_EMA.loc[start:end,"MSFT"], label = "20 EMA")

ax1.set_ylabel("Price in $")
ax1.legend(loc = "best")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_year_month_fmt)

ax2.plot(trading_positions_final.loc[start:end, :].index, trading_positions_final.loc[start:end, "MSFT"], label = "Positions")

ax2.set_ylabel('Positions')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_year_month_fmt)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you include the details of the error you're receiving, or the behaviour you were expecting and the actual behaviour, in the body of the question? This will help people identify the specific problem you're encountering. Additionally, since you've mentioned you're following a tutorial, it may be helpful to link to the tutorial you're following as a point of reference.

Comment: Tutorial:  https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-finance-part-3-moving-average-trading-strategy/          I expect two plots first with chart ,  moving averages , and entry points  , second plot - that's positions chart ( between 1 and -1)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 35, in <module>
    ax1.plot(data.loc[start:end, :].index, data.loc[start:end,"MSFT"], label = "Price")
 line 1762, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
 line 1277, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
 line 701, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers